# Regarding equality of angles of a hyperbolic polygon

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $P$ be a hyperbolic $4n$ gon having opposite sides with equal length and the sum of all interior angles is $2\pi$. Then is true that opposite angles are equal also?

Comment: No, it is not true. It is easy to construct a $4{\cdot}n$-gon with all sides equal and angles $\alpha,\beta,\alpha,\beta,\dots$ for $\alpha\ne \beta$ (so $n\cdot (\alpha+\beta)=\pi$). Then you cut a quadrangle by a diagonal and flip it. It brakes equality of opposite angles.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Thank you for your comment. Here if we consider the polygon $P$ as a polyhedral representation of a $g$ genus compact orientable surface with opposite side pairing then will it be true that the opposite angles are equal?

Comment: it seems that you repeat the same question, is not it?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin If we fix the orientation of the edges then the fliping will reverse the orientation then resulted polygon give some different surface.

Comment: The gluing should be done along the same rule (ignoring switching of sides).